# Drawing a UIBezierPath to UIImage to Base64 Image not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, base64, cgpath

I created some code to create a `UIBezierPath` within a `UIImage` context. Then take the image and create a base64 string. I believe I am supposed to draw the path within the beginning and end of the `UIImage`. However after many hours, it is not working. I am copying the base64 string to a website to download the image to see if it works. I am writing this in playground:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(200, 200), false, 0.0)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.lineWidth = 2
path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(100, 0))

path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(200, 40))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(160, 140))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(40, 140))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(0, 40))
path.closePath()

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let b64 = data?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
print(b64!)
```

The resulting PNG is 1000x1000 I am guessing because of my retina display. The image itself is completely transparent and nothing is visible. I am using this site to decode base64 and save a file, I've tried 2 others to see if it was the site. http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp

**EDIT**
I just tried the following code to see if the issue with with my image or bezier or saving to bas64. This code worked great. So I think it's a problem with my bezier.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://i.imgur.com/crr4m48.jpg")!)!)!

let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
let b64 = data?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
print(b64!)
```

Comment: Is the problem in creating the image, or converting to Base64? Those are two entirely unrelated operations. Save the PNG data to a file and see if you can open that image file. If so, the problem is with your Base64 conversion. Also, load some pre-existing image and use *that* as the input to your Base64 code -- what happens?

Comment: @Caleb I just tested with loading from a URL and it worked. It's my `UIBezierPath` that is funky somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're doing things out of order. For example:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(200, 200), false, 0.0)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

Why are you getting `image` before you draw anything into the graphics context? I think you're going to get an empty image -- it's not like the image you get at the outset will change as you draw things in the context. Wait to get the image until after you finish all your drawing. Also, the docs for that function say:

> *You should call this function only when a bitmap-based graphics context is the current graphics context. If the current context is nil or was not created by a call to UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, this function returns nil.*

So, make sure that you've satisfied that requirement and that the image you get back when you do call `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` is not `nil`.

Next, you're creating a bezier path:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.lineWidth = 2
path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(100, 0))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(200, 40))
//...
```

but in order for that path to actually be drawn in your context, you have to do something that draws, such as calling `path.fill()` or `path.stroke()`. I don't see that anywhere, so even if you fix the first problem above, you're still going to end up with an empty image until you do some drawing.

Comment: You are absolutely right This works 100%.  I needed to call `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` after I create the shape path and call `path.stroke()` to put the thing into motion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with the image context directly. You can try create `CGContextRef` with current image context like:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(200, 200))
var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
```

And then directly add your path to it:

```
CGContextAddPath(context, path)
```

Or you can create you curves with context methods like `CGContextAddCurveToPoint` and then stroke path with:

```
CGContextStrokePath(context)
```

And the last action to create image from it:

```
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

One more Point In addition to @Caleb :-

If you are drawing image.png which result of **1000x1000 pixels** then  **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext** parameter must be different as above one  :-

```
    //Swift-3 Syntax
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( CGSize(width:500, height:500 ), false , 2.0 )
```

[image]

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/HandlingImages/Images.html)